# StackOverflowError while retrieving User list

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, datatables

I was trying to get a list of users using bootstrap's datatables but I keep getting  `StackOverflowError`. Below is my code.

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/login_management", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loginMgt(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap m) {
    m.put("login_management", true);
    return new ModelAndView("login_management");
}
```

**(Datatables Object)**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/usersList", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Object userListPaginationDataTables(@RequestParam(value = "sEcho", required = false) String sEcho,
                                                            @RequestParam(value = "sSearch", required = false) String sSearch,
                                                            @RequestParam(value = "sColumns", required = false) String sColumns,
                                                            @RequestParam(value = "iDisplayStart", required = false) Integer iDisplayStart,
                                                            @RequestParam(value = "iDisplayLength", required = false) Integer iDisplayLength,
                                                            @RequestParam(value = "iColumns", required = false) Integer iColumns,
                                                            @RequestParam(value = "iSortCol_0", required = false) Integer iSortCol_0,
                                                            @RequestParam(value = "iSortColumnIndex", required = false) Integer iSortColumnIndex,
                                                            @RequestParam(value = "sSortDir_0", required = false) String sSortDir_0)
                                                                    throws IOException {
        String json = "";

        List<User> result = new ArrayList<>();

        result = userService.getUserList(iDisplayStart, iDisplayLength);

        int total = userService.getUserTotalSize();

        json = getJSonString(result, total);


    return json;
}

private static String getJSonString(List<?> result, int total){

    String json="";

    try {
        DataTablesObject dataTablesObject = new DataTablesObject();
        dataTablesObject.setAaData(result);
        if(total > 0) {
            dataTablesObject.setiTotalRecords(total);
            dataTablesObject.setiTotalDisplayRecords(total);
        }

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

        json = gson.toJson(dataTablesObject);

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        LOGGER.fatal(ex);
    }

    return json;
}
```

**login_management.jsp:**

```
<script>
    $(function() {          
        $("#example2").dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/usersList",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bFilter":false,
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "bJQueryUI": true,                  
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "id" },
                { "mData": "login" },
                {
                    "mData": null,
                    "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                        //alert(data);
                        return "<form method='post' action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/editUser?id=1'>"+
                                    "<button type='submit'class='btn btn-primary'>Edit</button>"+
                                "</form>";

                    },
                    "fnCreatedCell": function ( cell ) {
                        $('input, label', cell)
                            .button( {
                                text: true
                            } );

                    }
                }

            ]
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String login;

private String password;


@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch =FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="user_roles",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
)
private Role role;

//...getters & setters...
}
```

Roles:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Role {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String role;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch =FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="user_roles", 
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
)
private Set<User> userRoles;
//...getters and setters...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="user_roles")
public class UserRole {

@Id
@Column(name="user_id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name="role_id")
private Integer roleId;
//...getters and setters...
}
```

However after I compiled and startup my tomcat, I was getting this error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path  threw exception     [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beforeName(JsonWriter.java:580)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:401)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:495)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.write(TypeAdapters.java:246)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.write(TypeAdapters.java:231)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:91)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:206)
at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:894)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:91)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:206)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:91)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:206)
at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:894)
```

What is causing this?

Comment: Is that the whole stack overflow error log?

Comment: yes but it contains critical information which is missing in the cut out up there, you need to put the full message in

Comment: You need to tell gson to not keep wrapping references to Role and User. You want to serialize the Roles for the User, but you don't want to serialize the same user into each Role object. You want to mark the User field on the role as non-serializable.